# Update model object with new dynamicaly created field?

Tags: django, json, serialization, django-models

I have Queryset:
`queryset = Status.objects.all()[:10]`

Model `Status` hasn't got field `commentAmount` so I would add it to every object in Queryset:

```
for s in queryset:
    s.commentAmount = s.getCommentAmount()
```

All is fine, `print s.commentAmount` shows good results, but after:

```
response = HttpResponse()
response['Content-Type'] = "text/javascript"
response.write(serializers.serialize("json", queryset))

return response
```

I have not field `commentAmount` in returning JSON file. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `commentAmount` is not showing up is because when Django does the serialization, it loops through the fields declared on the model and only those fields.

Consider looping through your queryset in a template and creating the json manually or using another serialization tool such as [simplejson](http://undefined.org/python/#simplejson).